# Watching '$route' in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Watching the route with `(to, from)` is easy.

This issue i'm having is to know when I moved between 'top' components.

What I mean is that I have 2 routes:

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: '/home',
    children: [
       {
          path '',
          redirect: 'a'
       },
       {
          path: 'a',
          component: A,
          children: [
             {
              .....
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          path: 'b',
          component: B,
          children: [
             {
              .....
             }
          ]
       }
    ]    
}
```

The problematic scenario: I navigate from Component A nested child to Component B, and then clicked BACK to the same nested component of A.

In '`from`' and  '`to`' I can only see the 'A' routes (full match + matches).
I have NO IDEA I came from component B.

How can I have access to this type of information?